# ServerSignature not working

Tags: 14.04

I installed modsecurity earlier today but I didnt like it, so I uninstalled it. After that my "ServerSignature off" doesnt work.

I got:

```
ServerSignature off
ServerTokens Prod
```

in the end of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

When I go to my website in the web browser I cannot see the server version.

But if I curl into my website I can see:

```
<address>232 Server at <a href="mailto:[no address given]">*******.pw</a> Port 80</address>
```

It wont remove it! Please help me.

**OS:** Ubuntu 14.04

**Apache2 version:** Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to askubuntu.com! Some arguments in Apache configuration might be case sensitive. Have you tried `ServerSignature Off` instead of `ServerSignature off`?

Comment: @honza-kasik Hi, thanks! :) I edited "off" to Off, it didnt work. I did restart apache2 after my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older one but couldn't find a solution after digging for a while.

**TLDR:** Check every file referenced from your main apache2.conf (look for "Include...") for conflicting directives. In my case, particularly /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf. Try grepping recursively for the name of the directive you are having trouble with.

I was also having trouble getting these directives to apply in apache2.conf on 20.04 LTS -using the suggestions that I saw on many other sites to place them there- and it turned out to be caused by not putting them at the *very* end of the file. I mistakenly tried to place them where I felt they flowed nicely with existing config.

Though, after some research, I actually decided to modify **/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf** instead since the root cause turned out to be that ServerSignature and ServerTokens directives were already specified there using opposing settings.

The reason my entries got ignored was because the call out to 'IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf' was the last entry in the apache2.conf file. So, mine got overwritten by the default settings.

Grep to the rescue:

The way I discovered this was by running

```
grep -r 'ServerSignature' /etc/apache2/*
```

Which turned up the result

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf:ServerSignature Off
```

And that got used because the enabled config file is symlinked back to the "available" config

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jun 14 13:39 /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf -> ../conf-available/security.conf
```

So, in the security.conf file I changed the ServerSignature and ServerTokens directives to "Off" and "Prod", respectively. This resolved the problem for me.